# Resolving final URL of a hyperlink including meta and javascript redirects

Tags: c#, .net

I have a database full of URLs which redirect to a final destination URL. I need to resolve the final destination URL.

Some redirect by 301/302 headers which can be resolved fairly easily like so:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(destination);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine(response.ResponseUri);
```

However most are redirected by javascript, meta-redirects or possibly some other client side ways.
As the original URLs come from a variety of sources I cannot parse the HTML to look for a specific piece of javascript.

I think the only way is to fire up a web browser from within the console application using the original URL, wait a few seconds for it to redirect and then query the final URL. Can anyone suggest which built in .NET assemblies/COM objects could be used or a decent library and perhaps some sample code.

Also be interested in alternative solutions. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any generalized way to recognize JavaScript redirects *other than* firing up a web browser of some sort to interpret the JavaScript. That said, there's a `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` control that you may be use for such a purpose without needing to delegate to an external application. You can, of course, still interact with the control while it is hidden. It has various events you could attach to in order to detect when a redirect has occurred.